# Convert pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame type Dataframe to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark Dataframe and I need to convert this into python dictionary.

Below code is reproducible:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd = sc.parallelize([Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80),Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80),Row(name='Alice', age=10, height=80)])
df = rdd.toDF()
```

Once I have this dataframe, I need to convert it into dictionary.

I tried like this

```
df.set_index('name').to_dict()
```

But it gives error. How can I achieve this

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to first convert to a `pandas.DataFrame` using `toPandas()`, then you can use the `to_dict()` method on the transposed dataframe with `orient='list'`:

```
df.toPandas().set_index('name').T.to_dict('list')
# Out[1]: {u'Alice': [10, 80]}
```

Comment: But your output is not correct right? I want the ouput like this `{name: [age, height]}`

Comment: so the output should be {Alice: [5,80]} with no 'u'

Comment: I would discourage using Panda's here. Panda's is a large dependancy, and is not required for such a simple operation.

Comment: This is why you should share expected output in your question, and why is age `5`  instead of `10`? You should have unique records if you intend to create a dictionary.

Answer (score 36):

Please see the example below:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> df = (sc.textFile('data.txt')
            .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
            .toDF(['name','age','height'])
            .select(col('name'), col('age').cast('int'), col('height').cast('int')))

+-----+---+------+
| name|age|height|
+-----+---+------+
|Alice|  5|    80|
|  Bob|  5|    80|
|Alice| 10|    80|
+-----+---+------+

>>> list_persons = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect())
>>> list_persons
[
    {'age': 5, 'name': u'Alice', 'height': 80}, 
    {'age': 5, 'name': u'Bob', 'height': 80}, 
    {'age': 10, 'name': u'Alice', 'height': 80}
]

>>> dict_persons = {person['name']: person for person in list_persons}
>>> dict_persons
{u'Bob': {'age': 5, 'name': u'Bob', 'height': 80}, u'Alice': {'age': 10, 'name': u'Alice', 'height': 80}}
```

The input that I'm using to test `data.txt`:

```
Alice,5,80
Bob,5,80
Alice,10,80
```

First we do the loading by using pyspark by reading the lines. Then we convert the lines to columns by splitting on the comma. Then we convert the native RDD to a DF and add names to the colume. Finally we convert to columns to the appropriate format.

Then we collect everything to the driver, and using some python list comprehension we convert the data to the form as preferred. We convert the `Row` object to a dictionary using the `asDict()` method. In the output we can observe that Alice is appearing only once, but this is of course because the key of Alice gets overwritten.

Please keep in mind that you want to do all the processing and filtering inside pypspark before returning the result to the driver.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Hi Fokko, the print of list_persons renders "<map object at 0x7f09000baf28>" for me. Any help?

Comment: Wrap list around the map i.e. list_persons = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect()))

Comment: Brilliant way to do it!

Answer (score 5):

RDDs have built in function asDict() that allows to represent each row as a dict.

If you have a dataframe df, then you need to convert it to an rdd and apply asDict().

```
new_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict(True))
```

One can then use the new_rdd to perform normal python map operations like:

```
# You can define normal python functions like below and plug them when needed
def transform(row):
    # Add a new key to each row
    row["new_key"] = "my_new_value"
    return row

new_rdd = new_rdd.map(lambda row: transform(row))
```

Answer (score 4):

One easy way can be to collect the row RDDs and iterate over it using dictionary comprehension. Here i will try to demonstrate something similar:

Lets assume a movie dataframe:

movie_df

| movieId | avg_rating |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.92 |
| 10 | 3.5 |
| 100 | 2.79 |
| 100044 | 4.0 |
| 100068 | 3.5 |
| 100083 | 3.5 |
| 100106 | 3.5 |
| 100159 | 4.5 |
| 100163 | 2.9 |
| 100194 | 4.5 |

We can use dictionary comprehension and iterate over the row RDDs like below:

```
movie_dict = {int(row.asDict()['movieId']) : row.asDict()['avg_rating'] for row in movie_avg_rating.collect()}
print(movie_dict)
{1: 3.92,
 10: 3.5,
 100: 2.79,
 100044: 4.0,
 100068: 3.5,
 100083: 3.5,
 100106: 3.5,
 100159: 4.5,
 100163: 2.9,
 100194: 4.5}
```

Comment: `row.movieId : row.avg_rating` would be clearer in a non-parametrized script

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two-liner for very simple cases. Something more versatile might use a lambda and `asDict` to produce the value.

Assuming DataFrame `df` with `key`, `val` strings containing column names:

```
list = df.select(key, val).collect()
dict = {row[key]: row[val] for row in list }
```