# In SQL how do I group by every one of a long list of columns and get counts, assembled all into one table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, analytics, multilabel-classification

I have performed a stratified sample on a multi-label dataset before training a classifier and want to check how balanced it is now. The columns in the dataset are:

```
|_Body|label_0|label_1|label_10|label_100|label_101|label_102|label_103|label_104|label_11|label_12|label_13|label_14|label_15|label_16|label_17|label_18|label_19|label_2|label_20|label_21|label_22|label_23|label_24|label_25|label_26|label_27|label_28|label_29|label_3|label_30|label_31|label_32|label_33|label_34|label_35|label_36|label_37|label_38|label_39|label_4|label_40|label_41|label_42|label_43|label_44|label_45|label_46|label_47|label_48|label_49|label_5|label_50|label_51|label_52|label_53|label_54|label_55|label_56|label_57|label_58|label_59|label_6|label_60|label_61|label_62|label_63|label_64|label_65|label_66|label_67|label_68|label_69|label_7|label_70|label_71|label_72|label_73|label_74|label_75|label_76|label_77|label_78|label_79|label_8|label_80|label_81|label_82|label_83|label_84|label_85|label_86|label_87|label_88|label_89|label_9|label_90|label_91|label_92|label_93|label_94|label_95|label_96|label_97|label_98|label_99|
```

I want to group by every `label_*` column once, and create a dictionary of the results with positive/negative counts. At the moment I am accomplishing this in PySpark SQL like this:

```py
# Evaluate how skewed the sample is after balancing it by resampling
stratified_sample = spark.read.json('s3://stackoverflow-events/1901/Sample.Stratified.{}.*.jsonl'.format(limit))
stratified_sample.registerTempTable('stratified_sample')

label_counts = {}
for i in range(0, 100):
  count_df = spark.sql('SELECT label_{}, COUNT(*) as total FROM stratified_sample GROUP BY label_{}'.format(i, i))
  rows = count_df.rdd.take(2)
  neg_count = getattr(rows[0], 'total')
  pos_count = getattr(rows[1], 'total')
  label_counts[i] = [neg_count, pos_count]
```

The output is thus:

```py
{0: [1034673, 14491],
 1: [1023250, 25914],
 2: [1030462, 18702],
 3: [1035645, 13519],
 4: [1037445, 11719],
 5: [1010664, 38500],
 6: [1031699, 17465],
 ...}
```

This feels like it should be possible in one SQL statement, but I can't figure out how to do this or find an existing solution. Obviously I don't want to write out all the column names and generating SQL seems worse than this solution.

Can SQL do this? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do this  (and you surely aren’t the first to want to do so).

Comment: @Bohemian It looks like a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(label_0) as pos_0, ...` will work well. I do have to generate SQL but it isn't so bad in one statement like this. Thanks to @Marl for figuring this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate sql without group by.

Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(label_k) as positive_k ,.. FROM table
```

And then use the result to produce your dict {k : [total-positive_k, positive_k]}

Comment: This seems like the best option, and I'm a little embarrassed I didn't see this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do that in one statement but I am not sure the performances will be good.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

dataframes_list = [
    stratified_sample.groupBy(
        "label_{}".format(i)
    ).count().select(
        F.lit("label_{}".format(i)).alias("col"),
        "count"
    )
    for i in range(0, 100)
]

count_df = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.union(b),
    dataframes_list
)
```

This will create a dataframe with 2 columns, `col` which contains the name of the column you are counting, and `count` the value of the count.

To change it to a dict, I let you read [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206255/convert-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-type-dataframe-to-dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with single sql, to get all pos and neg counts

```
sql = 'select '
for i in range(0, 100):
    sql = sql + ' sum(CASE WHEN label_{} > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as label{}_pos_count, '.format(i,i)
    sql = sql + ' sum(CASE WHEN label_{} < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as label{}_neg_count'.format(i,i)
    if i < 99:
        sql = sql + ', '

sql = sql + ' from stratified_sample '
df = spark.sql(sql)
rows = df.rdd.take(1)
label_counts = {}
for i in range(0, 100):
    label_counts[i] = [rows[0][2*i],rows[0][2*i+1] ]

print(label_counts)
```