# How to convert dataframe column to dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

Firstly, I want to thank everybody for any help in advance!
I have 4 tables, I joined them and got a PySpark dataframe. One of the dataframe columns looks like this and it has about 200 000 records:

```
{"table_name":"BTR.DAILY_BTR.JSC_MON","login":"0015471"}
{"table_name":"BTR.DAILY_BTR.ESHOP.JSC_MON","login":"0015471"}
```

The type of this column is 'string'. I need to get value by key **table_name**. I tried to use json method .loads:

```
sparam = t1.select(col('ADD_PARAMS'))
json.loads(sparam)
```

But I got error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame
```

Then I tried to change the column type:

```
   sparam = t1.select(col('ADD_PARAMS').cast('string'))
   type(sparam)
```

It shows that the type is dataframe:

```
   pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

Anyway i tried to use method "loads" again:

```
   json.loads(sparam)
```

But I got the same error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame
```

I tried to use different options to get value of table_name ranging from converting to json, dict, regex, splits, but nothing helped.

**UPD**

Here is some of the code which is used:

```
import io
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import findspark
findspark.init('/mnt/nfs-spark/spark-2.3.3/')
findspark.find()
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


survey_requests = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/gluster-storage/etl/download/surv/survey_requests/*')
channels = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/gluster-storage/etl/download/surv/channels')
channel_segments = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/gluster-storage/etl/download/surv/channel_segments'))
channel_branches = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/gluster-storage/etl/download/surv/channel_branches'))
channel_touchpoints = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/gluster-storage/etl/download/surv/channel_touchpoints'))

t1 = (c.join(cs, c.IDD_SEGMENT == cs.ID_SEGMENT, "left")\
        .join(ct, ct.ID_TOUCHPOINT == c.IDD_TOUCHPOINT, "left")\
        .join(cb, cb.ID_BRANCH == c.IDD_BRANCH, "left"))\
        .join(survey_requests, c.ID_CHANNEL == survey_requests.CHANNEL_ID, 'right')



   sparam = t1.select(col('ADD_PARAMS').cast('string'))
   type(sparam)
   pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
   json.loads(sparam)
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame type Dataframe to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206255/convert-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-type-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Comment: @KalebaKBKeitshokile Thanks for the answer! But unfortunately not, the problem is that the entire column, which is essentially a dictionary, is of the string type. Your example is a bit different.

Comment: Ok well, make sure to include enough code in your question to reproduce your problem. It's one of the guidelines for question-asking on SO. But don't include so much code that isn't essential

Comment: @KalebaKBKeitshokile Added the main part of the code

Comment: The code should include all imports and helper functions so it can be copied and run locally.

Comment: You should be able to use `ast.literal_eval` from the built-in `ast` module to convert that string to a dictionary, if you can apply that function to the whole column.  In pandas, you would use `apply`.  Not sure about PySpark.  It looks like `json.loads` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

It's `.cast('string')`, not `.cast('str')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But unfortunately this did not help when converting to json, I get the following error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame

Comment: It did fixed the 1st issue and you changed the question