# Convert a pyspark dataframe into a dictionary filtering and collecting values from columns

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I need to convert this DataFrame to a dictionary:

| ID | value-1 | value-2 | value-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | Approve | NULL | NULL |
| 2B | Approve | Approve | NULL |
| 3C | NULL | NULL | Approve |

output:

```
{'1A': [value-1], '2B': [value-1,value-2], '3C': [value-3]}
```

Notice that I am using values of the first column of the DataFrame as keys to the dictionary.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried till now? `StackOverFlow` isn't a service that builds code from scratch.

Comment: please refer to this answer [Here i have explained the way to convert dataframe into desired dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879705/how-to-convert-a-dataframe-into-a-json-file-assigning-a-specific-schema-using-py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame type Dataframe to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206255/convert-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-type-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this, based on [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html) an [`array_remove`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_remove.html):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Set column to be used to get keys of the dict 
# and columns to be used to compute the values of the dict
dict_key = df.columns[0]
entry_cols = df.columns[1:]

{
    r[dict_key]: r.dict_entry
     for r in (
        df
        .select(
            dict_key,
            F.array_remove(
                F.array(*[
                    F.when(F.col(c) == 'Approve', F.lit(c)).otherwise('NULL')
                    for c in entry_cols
                ]),
                'NULL',
            ).alias('dict_entry')
        )
        .collect()
    )
}
```

This is the result:

```bash
{'1A': ['value-1'], '2B': ['value-1', 'value-2'], '3C': ['value-3']}
```

Comment: If the column names have '.' (dot) in its name, then the above code fails.

Comment: If you have dots in column names, you can wrap the name in a pair of "`". Check [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-refer-column-name-with-dot/) for some examples. So, you can easily adapt the code in the answer to that scenario.

Comment: Using  ```backticks(`)``` do work if we are referencing column name directly.  But in our code, we are using ```for c in entry_cols``` to send column name to ```F.col(c)``` and ```F.lit(c)```. So how exactly do we use backtick here? I am asking this because, I used ```F.col(`c`)``` and it failed. It is the same case when I used, ```F.lit(`c`)```

Comment: You have to change the string in the `c` variable, adding backticks, I think.