# How to convert a dataframe into a JSON file assigning a specific schema using pyspark?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark

I am using PySpark and I want to convert a Spark DataFrame into a specific JSON file.

the Dataframe is like this:

```
| Key  | desc | value |
|:---- |:----:| -----:|
| 12345| type | AA    |
| 12345| id   | q1w2e3|
| 98765| type | BB    |
| 98765| id   | z1x2c3|
```

I need to convert it into a JSON like this:

```
{
  "12345": {
     "type":"AA,
     "id":"q1w2e3"
    },
  "98765":{
     "type":"BB",
     "id":"z1x2c3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First collect the dataframe

```
Output = df.collect()
```

if you try to print the “Output” you will get List of Row Tuple something like this

> [Row(key:1234,desc:type,value:AA)…..]

Now iterate over this list using for loop and Create dictionary and assign these value
you can directly access them like this.

```
For row in Output:
     dict[key] = row[key]
```

once the dictionary is create then you can use `Json.dumps(dict)`

Comment: Important note on this solution: collect() can give you an OOM exception on the driver if the dataframe being collected (plus the JVM overhead) > driver memory. Use collect ONLY for those data sizes for which you are certain will not wreck your driver instance.